# irreducibility of an affine algebraic set $V((p))$ with $p$ irreducible

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have a little question about affine algebraic sets. Let $V$ be such a set ie. $$V=V(J)=\{(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in k^n:f(a_1,\dots,a_n)=0\text{ for all }f\in J\}$$ for an ideal $J\subset k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$.

> If I want to show irreducibility of a set $V((p))$, ie. $J=(p)$, is it enough to show that $p\in k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ is an irreducible polynomial?

I know that $V=V(J)$ is irreducible if and only if $$I(V)=\{f\in k[x_1,\dots,x_n]:f(a_1,\dots,a_n)=0\text{ for all }(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in V\}$$ is a prime ideal.

So $V((p))$ ($p$ irreducible) is irreducible  if and only if $I(V((p)))$ is a prime ideal. Do we have $I(V((p)))=(p)$? If yes, I am done.

Remark. This is no excersise so the answer of the question in the yellow box may be no.

Comment: We have $I(V((p))) = \sqrt{(p)}$.  Fortunately, $\sqrt{(p)} = (p)$ if $p$ is irreducible. (Note that non-irreducible polynomials may give irreducible varieties, as long as they have only one irreducible factor.)

Comment: Thank you! But $\sqrt{(p)}=(p)$ must not hold for a non irreducible $p$. (But it can.) So if I want to know if $V((p))$ is an irred. variety and I can show that $p$ is a irred. polynomial then this is an irred. variety? If $p$ is not irred., then I can not conclude anything.

Comment: $V((p))$ is irreducible if and only if $p$ is a power of an irreducible.